# Making a comprehensive dictionary from a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

What is the simplest way to make a dictionary for a .txt file? Each word in the text file is separated by a space. Each word in the file should be a key (in the dictionary) whose value is all the words that follow it at some point in the file, including repeats.

So if the text file was:
    I like cats and dogs. Dogs like cats. I like dogs more.

The dictionary would be:

```
d = {'I': ['like', 'like'], 'like': ['cats', 'cats', 'dogs'], 'cats': ['and', '. ']...
```

...and on until all words have become keys.

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't show the code I have so far because I'm an extreme beginner and hardly know what I'm doing. Also, it looks terrible. But, here's some:

```
def textDictionary(fileName):
    p = open(fileName)
    f = p.read()
    w = f.split()
    newDictionary = {}
    for i in range(len(w)):
        newDictionary[w[i]] = w[i+1]
    return newDictionary
```

Now this certainly shouldn't do everything I want yet, but shouldn't it at least return:

{'I': 'like', 'like': 'cats', 'cats': 'and'...}

...and so on?

Yet it gives me something completely different.

Comment: While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem and provide a helpful answer if you show us what you've already tried. Here's some info on how to provide [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a job for a `defaultdict` to me.  First you need to decide how to split the words -- For simplicity, I'll just split on whitespace, but this may be a job for regex since you have punctuation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

with open('textfile') as fin:
    data = fin.read()
    words = data.split()

for i, w in words:
    try:
        d[w].append(words[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        pass  # last word has no words which follow it...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to iterate over the words in two concurrent loops, offset by one. To do this, use `zip` on both the original list and the list `[1:]`.

This iteration will be your key and value to the dict. Or rather in this case, `defaultdict`. A `defaultdict` created with `list`, initializes every key with an empty list automatically. Thus you can `append` as needed without setting an initial value

```
from collections import defaultdict

def textDictionary(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as p:  # with to open and automatically close
        f = p.read()
        w = f.split()

    newDictionary = defaultdict(list)
    # defaultdict initialized with list makes each element a list automatically,
    # this is great for `append`ing

    for key, value in zip(w, w[1:]):
        newDictionary[key].append(value)  # easy append!

    return dict(newDictionary)  # dict() changes defaultdict to normal
```

File:

> I like cats and dogs like cats

Returns:

```
{'I': ['like'], 'and': ['dogs'], 'cats': ['and'], 'like': ['cats', 'cats'], 'dogs': ['like']}
```

---

I notice in this case `like` is followed by `cats` twice. If you only want one, initialize the `defaultdict` with `set` instead of `list`, and use `.add` instead of `.append`

[Documentation on zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)
[Documentation on defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Ok this works, but makes separate keys for words with punctuation differences like 'cats' and 'cats.', which I don't want. However, I do want the values to be differentiated (i.e., 'like': ['cats', as well as 'cats.']) based on the punctuation. Also, could I make a key that represents the end/beginning of a sentence? Like, there would be a key '&', whose values would be any word that begins a sentence at some point in the file? And this key '&' would also show up in the values of the other keys (i.e. 'cats': ['and', '&'] would be one entry).

Any way I could implement these changes?

Comment: Happy to hear this works! As to your new questions, you should probably go ahead and ask them as new questions by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. The Stack Overflow model is geared toward individual questions and specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the line from the file, you could do this:

```
line = 'I like cats and dogs. Dogs like cats. I like dogs more.'
line = line.replace('.', ' .') #To make sure 'dogs.' or 'cats.' do not become the keys of the dictionary.
op = defaultdict(list)
words = line.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if word not in '.': #To make sure '.' is not a key in the dictionary
        try:
            op[word].append(words[i+1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

The only thing you need to explicitly take care of, are full stops. The comments explain how the code achieves that. The above code results in:

```
{'and': ['dogs'], 'like': ['cats', 'cats', 'dogs'], 'I': ['like', 'like'], 'dogs': ['.', 'more'], 'cats': ['and', '.'], 'Dogs': ['like'], 'more': ['.']}
```